# Shortcut to Find a file and Navigate to it no longer works

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In VS2015, the shortcut to Find a file and Navigate it no longer works.

Where is the keybinding located for setting the shortcut to find and navigate to a file?

Specifically, I want to remap the "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>" shortcut to Find a file and Navigate to it.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The command name is **Edit.NavigateTo**. In VS 2015 RC the default keyboard shortcut to it is still `Ctrl + ,` in the Global scope.

Comment: Just a heads up, I was trying to use the keys: `Ctrl`, `+`, `,` together, but the actual hotkey is only `Ctrl`, `,` :).

Comment: German translation for this command is **Bearbeiten.Gehezuallen**. Somehow wasn't configured in my VS 2019.

Answer (score 7):

The shortcut is still `Ctrl + ,`, if you want to remap it you can go to Tools-->Options-->Environment to edit shortcuts. You may also restart VS or try to update to the latest version.

Comment: There's a later version of VS2015RC? What's the name of the command that I need to find to make the update?

Comment: Verified that we no longer need to restart vs 2015 after setting this option.

Comment: Even with VS2019 in the year 2021 this was applicable to me. Sometimes these shortcuts just get broken. I think in my case it's when I uninstall ReSharper, or when my settings sync to another install of VS that has it.

Answer (score 3):

For Mac os Version 1.13.1 (1.13.1) use CMD + P and then type the file name you want to open.