# Ctrl + , shortcut not working on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using visual studio 2015 version and **Navigate to** **[keyboard shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOy0U.png)**(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>) not working. (Or not configured)

How could I configure this custom using keyboard mappings in visual studio 2015?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358389/shortcut-to-find-a-file-and-navigate-to-it-no-longer-works

Comment: Thanks @SergeyVlasov. Resetting the *Edit.NavigateTo* command worked.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I can not reproduce the error in my environment. All is working well e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> for: Display the New Breakpoint window.

Please read:

- [Identifying and Customizing Keyboard Shortcuts in Visual
  Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx)
- [Default Keyboard Shortcuts in Visual
  Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx)

If you ever mess up your keyboard shortcuts and just want to reset all the shortcuts back to their default settings you can use the nuclear option by using the Reset button in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard:

[image]

When you click this button you will get following warning:

[image]

Take this warning seriously!  It will reset ALL keyboard mappings to their default values so this should only be used when things are really messed up with your shortcuts.

Comment: Worked.. Thank you, even though I still don't know why my shortcuts got messed up.